# Best way of secure communication model require for remote data transfer

Tags: c#, architecture, client-server, modeling, analysis

we have following scenario for our new project:

1) Organization have central office where main server with database is installed.
2) branch are all over the nation (currently limited to 10 branch)
3) Organization need very secure communication between branch and head office server.

And their need is:

1) Each branch will have client application built on C#, which will allow to save data to central server.

2) The client application cannot be used by unauthorized user or computer ( so i think VPN can be used)

3) Client application will have control over role and privilege, i.e. in the branch different user can login to system, and according to their role and privilege stored on central server application will start accordingly.

So What I want to know is, how that client server application can be built,

- which type of server application is good, window service or web service?
- How authentication & authorization can be done on application?
- how to prevent the client application to be distributed to other people who are not employee?
- What kind of communication technique should be used to transfer data from client to central server?

IN One sentence, I want some working model with full description to carry out the project.

Note: data are very confidential so organization does not want to use web application.

I hope you guys understand the scenario, if not please let me know.

Thank you, dying to see your model.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that anyone here is going to do effectively do your job for you and give you a "full description" of how to design such a system. The nature of the questions you're asking also suggest that your understanding of this space is limited. Perhaps you're not the right person to be carrying out such a project?

Comment: You have 10 minutes, starting... NOW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of things you need to consider while designing a distributed system. 
Web application should be the best option for distributed applications.

1. They can be accessed by users on any platform
2. Webapplications can be secured through https

Another option in .net would be smart clients factory pattern

Please refer msdn [patterns and practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650706) for .net solutions